# Sound lags by several seconds in some movies

Tags: audio, video, sync, lag, media-player-classic

I'm using the K-Lite Codec Pack and Media Player Classic.
In some movies (not all, so I guess it depends on codec) I've got sound lagging by several seconds, and this lags increases while movie is playing, so it's not just shifted by a constant, it... goes slower than video.

If I open the same movie in another player, like Windows Media Player or WinAmp, I see that the audio goes in sync, but the video starts lagging.

Do you know what can cause the problem?

Comment: Whats the video's file type?

Answer (score 3):

It may be worth trying [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) to play the file. If the problem continues, you can at least adjust the audio lag/lead to match the video.

Comment: I can't adjust the lag, cause it's increasing.

Comment: that just means you need to adjust it more than once.  VLC doesn't use system codecs, so it may be worthwhile to try it if your issues seem to be codec-related.

Answer (score -1):

Usually the file is just bad. I.s.o. downloading head over to your nearest videoshop and buy the dvd.